# Create a Cross image watermark in css

Tags: html, css

My need is to create a cross image that show like in the image. The Div 1 has no fixed height it will vary some times.
Then how can I create a cross watermark inside Div 1?

I tried Like

```
.cross01 {
width:520px;
height:100%;
background:url(../images/cross01.png) repeat-y;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
z-index:1000;

}
```

Comment: "Here I attached a copy of my website page" ..Where??

Comment: Sorry.Edited now Please have a look?

Comment: your website is very blurry!

Comment: What is the cross watermark intended to achieve? It should be relatively simple to do, but since end users will be able to remove it very easily, I'd worry that it may not actually achieve what you want.

Comment: @Spudley I want to put a watermark like a cross show in the image .the cross image must be inside the div 1 .the problem is the div 1 have no fixed height.when I put a cross image inside the Div 1 but when the height have some change then the cross image screw up.

Comment: How nice all these awnsers are, its hard to do by css. people with a little bit of knowledge go to your source and disable the css class and will save the image anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a wrapper to the images and use an after selector.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cNp8d/1/)

CSS

```
.watermark {
    position: relative;
}
.watermark:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="watermark">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BcAJJgyXL._SX450_.jpg"></img>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61BcAJJgyXL._SX450_.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: But  I need The Cross Mark.When I created a Cross image and put as background image.but when the div height vary then the cross image is screw up

Comment: Ah I see, I have updated the demo http://jsfiddle.net/cNp8d/2/ it now uses the css3 property background-size to cover the image, if you use a large image it wont stretch

Comment: but the watermark:after is not fetching when it will fetch?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about not fetching

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you are trying to achieve

Set the Div1 css position attribute as relative.  Create a child div with position absolute.
Insert the watermark image or text inside the child div.  Put all your content inside the parent div.  Position the watermark div above all your contents (use z-index:1).

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried like this

.cross01 {
width:520px;
height:100%;
background:url(../images/cross01.png) repeat-y;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
z-index:1000;

}

Comment: This is my DIV1 's css

.content-cart-wrapper .Div1 {
padding: 35px 11px 15px;
margin-bottom: -12px;
border: 0px none;
}


.Div1 {
border-bottom: #e0e0e0 2px solid;
}

Comment: Check this out, hope this help.........       http://jsfiddle.net/sajaycv/Pd8ut/