# CSS crossbar on dynamic DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a `DIV` in my html with dynamic size.Means its height may change according to different parameters.Now I need to put a cross bar through CSS in to this `DIV`.The youtput will look something like this
[image]

I have tried using some CSS

```css
 .DIV1{
    width:520px;
    height:100%;
    background:url(../images/cross01.png) repeat-y;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1000;
 }
```

But the problem of this code is that when the div comes in another height it breaks.As you may know this back ground image I am using won't grow according to my DIV height.So I am searching for any CSS solution.Can any one show me a path.

Comment: Confused...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856491/create-a-cross-image-watermark-in-css

Comment: ah I think a coworker also posted the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
background-size : auto 100%;
```

More info here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=50%25